# Docker/windowsfilter takes huge amount of diskspace

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

I am using docker for windows and I noticed my c drive was getting full. When i looked I noticed that there is 15 gb of data here: `Docker/windowsfilter`. I use docker sporadically so I do not need to keep any images or containers.

So I googled some and tried suggestions like `docker system prune` `docker image prune` and the same for containers etc.

This did not seem to work and I could not find another proper solution so in the end I tried an often mentioned tool `docker-ci-zap` however no luck here either

Finally I tried a factory reset of docker itself which as I understand should delete everything.

However `Docker/windowsfilter` is still 15 gb. How can I get rid of this data?

Comment: Did you try to uninstall docker? It deleted all images when I uninstalled it

Comment: No I have not tried that. I was hoping for a little less brute force solution

Comment: Actual install/reinstall of Docker will be the least amount of "brute force" compared to docker-zap stuff you already done.

Comment: @GregorySuvalian I ended up trying your solution and uninstalled Docker and have restarted my computer. No luck though.

Answer (score 6):

Try https://github.com/moby/docker-ci-zap. Just download `docker-ci-zap.exe` from that repo and run it `.\docker-ci-zap.exe -folder "C:\ProgramData\docker"`. Worked for me and it is much faster than reinstall Docker.

Comment: Took quite some time to execute, but worked perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the entire Docker folder inside ProgramData using the below trick, I hope this will also work for deleting the windowsfilter folder

Pre-requisite : Needs git bash to be installed

2. Run git bash
3. rm -rf windowsfilter\

I think the above workaround will also work with WSL terminal, but haven't tested myself

Comment: Removing folder leads to kind of not-working Docker

Comment: This helped for me to remove also `volumes` folder!